# What is the definition of xvdf?

Tags: filesystems

I was watching a lecture on Linux file systems and partitions. We are learning about MBR-based and GPT-based partitions. We run the commands `fdisk xvdf` and `gdisk xvdf`. But there is no clear definition of what `xvdf` is. The only mention is at the start:

> Inside of here you'll notice we have xvdf. This is our device that we'll create partitions on.

A search for `linux what is "xvdf"` has a lot of results that involve how to do things involving xvdf, but no definition. **What is xvdf**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xvd` in in `xvdf` stands for **Xen Virtual block Device**.

This is from a question on [ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166083/what-is-the-dev-xvda1-device) about `xvda`:

> You are on a Xen VPS(or virtual machine); **xvd* are simply the Xen disk storage devices (Xen Virtual block Device)**. They appear instead of sda, etc. when you are using the more efficient paravirtualized Xen disk drivers instead of straight-up SCSI disk emulation. If you list the installed modules (drivers) on a Xen HVM, this driver will show as blkfront (or xen_blk if you are running on a very old Xen version--pretty rare).

Xen refers to the Xen Project, defined on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen) as:

> Xen (pronounced /ˈzɛn/) is a type-1 hypervisor, providing services
>   that allow multiple computer operating systems to execute on the same
>   computer hardware concurrently.

`xvdf` is nothing but another extension for drives (i.e., the `f` in `xvdf` means nothing).

Comment: xvd stands for "Xen Virtual block Device" then? What does xvdf stand for?

Comment: The "xen-blkfront" driver, which allows the virtual machines to access the underlying block devices, traditionally mapped sda, sdb... to xvda, xvdb..., [...] & what xvdf stands for i am not sure.